# parallax эффект

Tags: веб-дизайн

Как быть с parallax эффектом в адаптивном дизайне? Ведь для мобильных устройств parallax тяжело.

Comment: тяжело что именно?

меньше результатов в гугле "как для мобильных устройств parallax тяжело"?

Comment: Не включайте параллакс, если определили, что смотрят с мобильного устройства.

@actionless: тяжело, видимо, пересчитывать позиции и перерендерить экран с прозрачностью слоёв по 10-30 раз в секунду.

Comment: Всмысле у них процессоры слабые.

Comment: слабые? да на десктопах сейчас почти такие же слабые стоят :)

Comment: Ну не знаю может это только у меня одного смартфон с 1ггц 300мб рам и 4 гб сд карта?